# Kotlin Firestore Query get all documents in Today

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I've written this query in Swift, and it works fine. This is the query in Kotlin:

```
ref.whereGreaterThan("dateAndTime", startOfToday)
            .whereLessThan("dateAndTime", endtOfToday)
            .whereEqualTo("hasNoDate", false)
            .whereEqualTo("is_archived", false)
```

Notice:

```
.whereGreaterThan("dateAndTime", startOfToday)
.whereLessThan("dateAndTime", endtOfToday)
```

I get startOfToday and endOfToday like so:

```
val startOfToday = LocalDateTime.now().withHour(0).withMinute(0).withSecond(0)
val endtOfToday = LocalDateTime.now().withHour(0).withMinute(0).withSecond(0).plusDays(1)
```

So I'm not sure if that's not the right format to query by in Kotlin?

I can confirm that `dateAndTime` field type in my firestore db is `timestamp`:
[image]

So I'm wondering if `LocalDateTime` is not the correct Date Util to use?

**Update** *Second failed attempt*

I've also tried to get the `Date()` objects, with these methods:

```
   fun getStartOfToday(): Date {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.time = Date() // Set your date object here

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
        return calendar.time // Your changed date object
    }

    fun getEndOfToday(): Date {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.time = Date() // Set your date object here

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59)
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59)
        return calendar.time // Your changed date object
    }
```

It's still not returning any tasks, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

This is the updated query:

```
 .whereGreaterThan("dateAndTime", this.getStartOfToday().toInstant())
 .whereLessThan("dateAndTime", this.getEndOfToday().toInstant())
 .whereEqualTo("hasNoDate", false)
 .whereEqualTo("is_archived", false)
```

Does anyone have any tips or pointers as to why it's not working?

This is the working code in Swift:

```
extension CollectionReference {
    func whereField(_ field: String, isDateInToday value: Date) -> Query {
        let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: value)
        guard
            let start = Calendar.current.date(from: components),
            let end = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: start)
        else {
            fatalError("Could not find start date or calculate end date.")
        }
        return whereField(field, isGreaterThan: start).whereField(field, isLessThan: end)
    }
}
```

It works perfectly, and you can see it uses both `isGreaterThan` and `isLessThan`.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated `calendar.time` to `calendar.time = Timestamp.now().toDate()` using Firebases Timestamp class, and it started working as expected!

```
   fun getStartOfToday(): Date {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.time = Timestamp.now().toDate()

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
    return calendar.time 
}

fun getEndOfToday(): Date {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.time = Timestamp.now().toDate()

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23)
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59)
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59)
    return calendar.time 
}
```

This is the updated query:

```
 .whereGreaterThan("dateAndTime", this.getStartOfToday().toInstant())
 .whereLessThan("dateAndTime", this.getEndOfToday().toInstant())
 .whereEqualTo("hasNoDate", false)
 .whereEqualTo("is_archived", false)
```